# org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: Schedule_assignedRoles, for columns: assignedRoles

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, mappingexception

I need a help, I'm trying to use a Map, but I got this error:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: Schedule_assignedRoles, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(assignedRoles)]
>       at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:390)
>       at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:363)
>       at org.hibernate.mapping.Collection.validate(Collection.java:310)
>       at org.hibernate.mapping.IndexedCollection.validate(IndexedCollection.java:74)
>       at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:333)
>       at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:443)
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:802)

here my code:

```
@Entity
public class Schedule extends PersistentObject implements Comparable<Schedule> {
   private String title;

   @ManyToOne
   private Agent target;

   @ElementCollection
   @MapKeyColumn(nullable = false)
   @Column(nullable = false)
   private Map<Long, List<Role>> assignedRoles = new HashMap<>();

   //gets e setters
}
```

thank's! :D

Comment: who told you it was possible to embed a value of type List in a Map using JPA?

Comment: I do not know, I think it was possible. thank's!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think using `@ManyToMany` or `@OneToMany` is enough for your task

```
@Entity
public class Schedule extends PersistentObject implements Comparable<Schedule> {

   @Column
   private String title;

   @ManyToOne
   private Agent target;

   @OneToMany 
   private List<Unit> units = new List<>();

}

@Entity
public class Unit {

  @ManyToMany 
  private List<Role> assignedRoles = new List<>();

}
```

Comment: Hey,
I need a map if it's possible, because schedule have to save a key(Unit, other object) with a list of roles.
Thank's anyway!

Comment: @renanlessa It is impossible to use a map. Probably, you need a yet another entity. I update.